# Get HWND of message sender

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to get the HWND of the window/app that sent a message to current app (using SendMessage/PostMessage) ? Of course, I mean without the sending app setting its own HWND in wparam/lparam.

Comment: That's not possible.  Best to describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of hoping for miracles.

Comment: Was trying to provide basic level of security, such as accepting messages only from registered sources. In this case, "registered sources" would be programs that would "sign-in" into the receiving app, providing some basic auth info. Not trying to provide foolproof security, but just a way to ignore spurious messages that could come from random apps.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew